# libGDX: Linking 3D scene from 2D screen

Tags: java, libgdx

Using libGDX I have created a few 2D screens, such as a splash screen and a main menu, and also created a 3D scene which I want to be able to load when clicking a button on the main menu.
I know how to add a listener but I don't know what command to use to show the 3D scene on the screen. If I use `setScreen(new World3D)` (or other similar extended methods) it gives me:
 `World3D cannot be cast to com.badlogic.gdx.Screen`

What I want to know is how to get from the 2D screen to the 3D scene. Do I wrap the 3D scene inside the screen or am I doing it right but my `World3D` class is not set up properly?
[Here](http://pastebin.com/GsqB4cVt) is a pastebin of my `World3D` class in case that is the problem.

NOTE: The classes are in separate sub-packages but the proper imports have been added in the required classes.